# SubQuery Doctrine With TOP 1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

Subquery in doctrine report error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"...
but i use setMaxResults(1); When i Print `$qb->getDQL()` this query not return `TOP 1`

```
$qb = $this->getEm('orm_test')
    ->getRepository('Test\Entity\Test')
    ->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb->select('a.test1')
    ->where('a.id = b.id')
    ->andWhere('a.date <= :date')           
    ->setMaxResults(1);

$qb->setParameters(array(
                           'date' => '2014-07-01'
    ));
```

and

```
$qb2 = $this->getEm('orm_test')
    ->getRepository('Test\Entity\Test2')
    ->createQueryBuilder('b');

$qb2->select('b.test1')
    ->where('a.date <= :date')
    ->andWhere('a.date >= (' . $qb->getDql() . ')')

$qb2->setParameters(array(
                           'date' => '2014-07-01'
    ));
```

this is an example only to draw my problem , the fact is that my `$qb->getDql()` does not return a value when placed as subquery

Comment: i removed ->setMaxResults(1)  and changed to ->select(max('a.test1')) ...I solved the problem.